# Cards have extra shadow on device?

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

simulator shows same shadows. in-app 6.0.1 shadows are more intense or moved by 1px down. HALP?

I added code for the card above (shadows behaving correctly) and the 3 new cards below (shadows doubled/offset). As you can see the card code is copied from the upper card and exactly the same, unless I missed something...

[image]
[image]

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:id="@+id/components"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"

                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:text="Components"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="#bbb"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/saddle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
                    android:text=""
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    />
                    </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <!--<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="#bbb"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    />-->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/seatpost"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
                    android:text=""
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
               <!-- <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="#bbb"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    />-->


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/handlebar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
                    android:text=""
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
               <!-- <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="#bbb"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    />-->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stem"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
                    android:text=""
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/repairref_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#808080"
                    android:text="Repair Reference"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/repairref_lineL"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#BFBFBF"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/repairref_txt"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/repairref_lineR"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#BFBFBF"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/repairref_txt"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:id="@+id/sheldonbrown"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/repairref_lineL"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/il_btn_rec_sheldonbrown"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:id="@+id/sheldonbrown"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/repairref_lineL"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/il_btn_rec_parktool"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:id="@+id/sheldonbrown"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/repairref_lineL"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/il_btn_rec_jimlangley"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bikeFeedback"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_animation_ripple_grey">
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#808080"
                android:text="BICYCLE FEEDBACK"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


                />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that there's nothing in the Java code setting the elevation?

Comment: Not that I can find. :/